# Eggplant not Launching

Tags: eggplant

After debugging this issue for a while, I'm at a loss.

Eggplant won't launch. Every time I start it, whether through the executable itself or the Eggplant.bat file, I receive the generic "Eggplant.exe has stopped working" dialogue box. 
[Dialogue Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zey5F.png)

I've done everything I can think of - restarted, re-installed, uninstalled all Eggplant software from my computer, re-installed again, updated, restarted, etc. etc.

My running file reads:

```
2018-07-19 10:34:33.457 Eggplant[9872:16304] NSDocumentClass EGGDocument not NSDocument subclass
2018-07-19 10:34:33.725 make_services[10528:7684] WARNING - unable to create shared user defaults!
```

Has anyone run into this problem? I can't find anything online about it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the user preferences file gets corrupted. Try renaming or deleting  %appdata%/eggplant/defaults/eggplant.plist.

Comment: When I uninstalled I removed all associated files & folders.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue and it appears to be related to the eggplant.plist file. The answer provided by Matt is based on the directory for Linux. In order to find this file in Windows go to the following directory:

C:\Users\%YOUR_USER_ID%\AppData\Roaming\Eggplant\Defaults

You will find the eggplant.plist file there, go ahead and delete this file and try running your eggplant again - this worked for me.